# Automatize adjust polygon bounds based on other polygon

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, metes-and-bounds

I have two polygons, as below:

[image]

Does exist an automatic way to adjust the vertices of Pink Polygon near of Blue Polygon bounds to Blue Polygon bounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ArcGIS you can use the [Snap tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001v00000007000000), which will do exactly what you need but is only available with Standard and Advanced licences. If you don't have this licences, you could use [integrate](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000002s000000), but then you don't have the control on which vertex is moving. Note that both tools modify your data, so you better work on a copy of your dataset.